# Convert Java Object/String to actual Class

Tags: java, class, testing, casting, annotations

I get a list of Java classes via:

```
List<String> cF = classFinder.findClassesInPackage("com.some.test", Info.class);
```

where `classFinder` is the service/class and `findClassesInPackage` method finds all the classes in a package `com.some.test` that has `@Info` annotations in them. `Info.class` is the second parameter which is nothing but the interface.

My list `cF` is now filled with following content:

```
[com.some.test.example.FollTest, com.some.test.example.SubsTest, ..]
```

Now, I convert this `List cF` to a `Set` to remove duplicate methods via:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(cF);
```

***OBJECTIVE***:

I want to `iterate` over this set so I can get all the `classes one-by-one` and finally get all the `Info` annotations in each class and print them. I need this as I will parse these annotation afterwards.

My concern: The set elements are now Strings and how do I convert them to actual Classes? `(For example: out of my first element in set: com.some.test.example.FollTest, I just want FollTest that too in class form)`

Here is what I am trying to do for a single element first:

`Object check = set.toArray()[0];` - still an Object/String and not the actual class which I want.

And then for reading the annotations (for example):

```
for (Annotation annotation : ClassName.class.getAnnotations()) {
            Class<? extends Annotation> type = annotation.annotationType();
            System.out.println("Values of " + type.getName());

            for (Method method : type.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                Object value = method.invoke(annotation, (Object[])null);
                System.out.println(" " + method.getName() + ": " + value);
            }
        }
```

`How do I get above ClassName? (although I have them in the String/Object form as part of list/set).`

***Updated question: Also, once I find the class name, how do I get all the annotations inside that class and print them out?***

Referred this:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Getannotationbyannotationclass.htm for how I can get the annotations in a particular class.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Class.forName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

**Example**:

```
String className = "com.some.test.example.FollTest";

Class c = Class.forName(className);

Annotation[] annotation = c.getAnnotations();
```

Comment: I get this: `[Ljava.lang.annotation.Annotation;@4475a0c6` as output from above code.

Comment: Do I have to trim the initial part? Until I reach FollTest? Also how will that  `getAnnotations()` work then?

Comment: I figured, accessing via for loop helps: `for (int i = 0; i < annotation.length; i++) { System.out.println(annotation[i]); }`